# Collapse xmm register into a scalar

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I need to be able to take a 4 packed integers, and collapse them, one on top of each other, into a single combined integer, using the or operation.

What's the most efficient way to do this? Note, the 1's in the packed integers would never have a common location, so I think an unsigned "add" could also do the trick.

I saw the horizontal add instruction, but it's for signed adds.

Comment: Which SIMD instruction set are you allowed to use?

Comment: Signed and unsigned addition is the same thing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller prefer sse2 but will go up to 4.1

Comment: have  you consulted https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ ?

Comment: @harold: oh, you've got a point. ooops; i was missing that. Ragdoll, have a look at how negative numbers are represented and why that is handy.

Comment: so with mm_hadd_epi32, putting the same register in for both operands, I would do this twice and i'd get the result in instrunctions in the lowest integer, i think. can you use the same register as both operands without a copy instruction? If you think this checks out, put it in an answer and ill vote it

Comment: That works, but that's one of those nasty 3-cycle operations, and you need two of them because it isn't a proper horizontal add but a "kinda horizontal add". You might as well do the regular shuffle/vertical-add thing then, which is pure SSE2. Edit: actually not "as well", it's better!

Comment: @harold could you put it in an answer? List the steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSSE3 way mentioned in the comments, with 2 `phaddd`'s would be something like this:

```
phaddd xmm0, xmm0
phaddd xmm0, xmm0
```

Unfortunately that's not very fast, 4 cycles on SB and 6 cycles on everything else (8 or 10 for AMD).

The plain SSE2 way with shuffles and normal adds can look something like this: (not tested)

```
pshufd xmm1, xmm0, 0x4E
paddd xmm0, xmm1
pshufd xmm1, xmm0, 0xB1
paddd xmm0, xmm1
```

Which takes 4 cycles on anything except AMD processors. Downsides: code is a big larger, and it needs a temporary register.